# How to add only positive numbers in shell script?

Tags: shell, sum

```
sum=0
for file in $*
do
  for number in `grep -wo "[0-9]*" $file`
  do
    if [ $number > 0 ]
    then
        sum=$(($sum+numar))
    fi
  done
done
echo "Suma este: $sum"
```

Comment: It would help if you also included a description of exactly what you were trying to do here and the contents of `$file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell does two kinds of comparison tests: lexicographic (string) and numeric.  The lexicographic ones are `=`, `>`, `<`, etc.  The numeric ones are `-eq`, `-gt`, `-lt`, etc.  When you say that you want "positive numbers", you are asking for numeric comparison.

There is a big difference between the two types.  Observe:

```
$ [ -2 > 0 ] && echo yes
yes
$ [ -2 -gt 0 ] && echo yes
```

The lexicographic comparison, `>`, thinks `-2` is greater than `0` because of the relative positions of `-` and `0` in the character set.  The numeric one, `-gt`, understands minus signs in terms of arithmetic.

Thus, the line `if [ $number > 0 ]`, does not do what you want.

`man bash` explains it as follows:

> ```
>    string1 = string2
>           True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.
>
>    string1 != string2
>           True if the strings are not equal.
>
>    string1 < string2
>           True if string1 sorts before string2 lexicographically.
>
>    string1 > string2
>           True if string1 sorts after string2 lexicographically
>
>    arg1 OP arg2
>           OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal  to,
>           not  equal  to,  less  than,  less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively.
>           Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or negative integers.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $number -gt 0 ]];
```

Also, see http://robertmuth.blogspot.nl/2012/08/better-bash-scripting-in-15-minutes.html?m=1 for more bash scripting guidelines.